# How to fix error in int to Binary String

Tags: java

I am trying to convert an integer to a binary number string, and I wrote the code for it and it compiled. However, I can't seem to write a test file for it, i keep getting an error. I am supposed to write a separate test file that outputs my answer, however I am not sure how to do that. I'm pretty new to Java. Can anyone help me figure out how to fix the error I get?

This is my java code for to convert it.

```
public String binaryNumber( int j)       
{

    String n = "";
    String a = "";


    do
    {
        a += (j % 2);
        j = j/2;         

    }while (j != 0);

    for(int r = (a.length() - 1); r >=0; r--)
     {
        n += a.charAt(r);
     }

    return n;
}

 public String getN {return n;}
```

This is my test code :

```
public class BinaryNumberTest
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
   {
    System.out.println("Result: " + binaryNumber(45));
   }

 }
```

Comment: Your `binaryNumber` must be static

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make your `binaryNumber` method `static` because you are not using instance fields.

```
public class BinaryNumber 
{
    public static String binaryNumber( int j)       
    {

        String n = "";
        String a = "";


        do
        {
            a += (j % 2);
            j = j/2;         

        }while (j != 0);

        for(int r = (a.length() - 1); r >=0; r--)
         {
            n += a.charAt(r);
         }

        return n;
    }
}
```

To test:

```
public class BinaryNumberTest
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
   {
    System.out.println("Result: " + BinaryNumber.binaryNumber(45));
   }

 }
```

Comment: Thank you for helping. I edited my original post with changes to the test code. Could you help me with that?

Answer (score 1):

**Your code seems correct if you make the `binaryNumber(int j)` method `static`.** Because you can't access non-static method inside static context.

However you can use `Integer.toBinaryString(x)` to perform the task easily. Additionally, you can use `Integer.toString(x,8)` to convert octal, `Integer.toString(x,2)` to convert binary, `Integer.toString(x,16)` to convert hexa-decimal, and `Integer.toString(x,n)` to n base.

Comment: I assume this is a homework question, where the purpose of the task is to do it manually. So using `Integer.toBinaryString(x)` would defeat the purpose. :)

Comment: Thank you, changing it to static did work. I edited my test code and now I get an error again. I need to put an integer and then call out to it in my test code. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

First, since `binaryNumber` doesn't use any instance members it could (read: should) be defined as `static`. Second, you need to reference it by its class name, or statically import it:

```
System.out.println("Result: " + BinaryNumber.binaryNumber(45));
```